# cannot access label in cocoa - basic cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, label, xcode4.5

I spent quite a few hours on this but could not resolve it. I follow this basic tutorial to create cocoa mac os application that has

- Text Control
- Button control
- Label Control

I created a new class, added NSString object, change the class name for NSString object to my class. Then I control+dragged text box, label to myclass.h (outlets). I did the same to button but this time selected action.

Now I put code in action to acess my label, I can't. They do not appear in intellesense. I have spent quite sometime on this. This is a very basic qeustion. what am I doing wrong? i am using XCODE 4.6.3.

```
------------------- .h file ---------------------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myclass : NSObject
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *mytextbox;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *mylabel;

@end

----------------- .c file ---------------------------
#import "myclass.h"

@implementation myclass

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender {
    [self.mytextbox.value setStringValue:@"hello there"];

    [mytextbox] (not accessible)
}
@end
---------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here was, I had to use underscore character before the variable (property) name. I don't know how why underscore work with and what is its purpose. I am new to xcode. So

```
_mytextbox  //worked
```

Comment: in modern compilers this is the default backing variable name if not otherwise specified with `@synthesize`. but it should not compile in the first place (and the error should tell you this exactly). Errors and warnings are meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

try to make it a NSTextField

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *mytextbox;
```

also fix it in your nib file.

Comment: did u change your nib file?

Comment: you need to have a text field there, not a plain view.

Comment: I do have an actual textfield. The above code is declaration of that textfield in my class.

Comment: a declaration doesnt ensure the instance variable is actually af a certain type. you must also create an object of that type or a subclass and assign it to that ivar. one way is to let the nib create it, or you do it in code.

Comment: that would make sense but then I am following [this tutorial](http://daniarnaout.com/tutorials/mac-os-x-development/mac-os-development-3-labels-buttons) and it works in the tutorial without any problem. The only thing is, I am prob using a newer version of Xcode (4.5)

Comment: I wont watch a tutorial video just to guess what you might understood wrong. and sure the xcode version is not that important. In your code you declared a view instead of a text field. so very likely you also got that in the nib wrong.

Comment: Well i tried this tutorial like 6 times. It looks like something basic but may be I am missing something. I will post my answer once I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a `.c file`, it should have a .m extension.  (or .mm if you want to use c++ code as well).  This is not just a style thing, it is necessary.

`[mytextbox] (not accessible)`

To access the mytextbox instance variable, you do self.mytextbox or [self mytextbox].

Comment: If I move the code to .m file, it throws error about @property. With self, I can access the mytextbox but then I cannot set it value using setStringValue (it is not their in intellisense).